# getBase64 inside a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to use getBase64 (to convert images to base64) inside a loop.
The thing is that the front print the same image all the times.

```
const cloneResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(previewDataResponse));

async function filesToBase64() {
      if (imageUpdate.length > 0) {
        console.log(imageUpdate);
        cloneResponse.response_json_new.finalResponse.image = await getBase64(imageUpdate[0]);
      }
      if(lateralImages.length > 0){
        for (let i of cloneResponse.response_json_new.lateral.item_lateral){ 
              for (let j of lateralImages){
          let my64 = j;             
          i.image_lateral[0].path_image_lateral = await getBase64(my64);
        }
        }
      }
    }
```

const lateralImages is an array of objects with this structure:

```
[{name: 'IMG_20211015_151052.jpg', lastModified: 1663252467419, lastModifiedDate: Thu Sep 15 2022 16:34:27 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 4178792}, {name: 'steps.jpg', lastModified: 1663236412688, lastModifiedDate: Thu Sep 15 2022 12:06:52 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central}]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is `cloneResponse` ? What does `front print the same image all the times` mean?

Comment: You always feed `imageUpdate[0]`  into your `getBase64`

Comment: @Felix imageUpdate[0] is print in the first conditional the problem is in the second conditional. i have a place to print images that i select in my browser, in my state i have all the images, but when i try to use all converted to base64 i see just the last image in all the places.

Comment: Now i see my error, if i do the loop inside the loop, all the values are changed every time for one, until the inside loop end to pass for all the first loop. For this at the end all the files are the same.

Answer (score 0):

At the end i change the code and did this:

```
for (let i of cloneResponse.response_json_new.lateral.item_lateral){            
            const image_to_base64 = lateralImages.find(file => file.name === i.image_lateral[0].path_image_lateral);
            i.image_lateral[0].path_image_lateral = await getBase64(image_to_base64);          
        }
```